# Reading command line arguments in a C program

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

What this does is converts the argument `./a.out -b 101` into a decimal 5 though what I am trying to do is only covert the 101 into a binary number if I give it the argument `-b`

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if ((argc == 3) && (argv[2] == "-b") ) //here lies the problem
  {
    int n = 0;
    char *c_pt = argv[2];

    printf("argv[1]: %s\n", argv[1]);
    while (*c_pt)
    {
      if (*c_pt < '0' || *c_pt > '1')
      {
        break;
      }
      n = n * 2 + *c_pt - '0';
      c_pt++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", n);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argument indexes count from 0 with the name of the program.  `argv[1]` contains the string `"-b"`, while `argv[2]` contains the string `"101"`.

Additionally, you need to `#include <string.h>` and use `strcmp()` to compare strings.

Internally, the number will be binary regardless of how you convert it.  However, there isn't an easy way of printing a binary number in C.  You can use `strtol()` (from `<stdlib.h>`), or one of its relatives, to convert the string as a binary value.  You should probably use that to convert the string into a value (though, in general, you need to be rather careful detecting the error conditions from `strtol()`; it is subtle with its returns).

> ### 7.20.1.4 The strtol, strtoll, strtoul, and strtoull functions
>
> ```
> long strtol(const char * restrict nptr, char ** restrict endptr, int base);
> ```
>
> ¶7 If the subject sequence is empty or does not have the expected form, no conversion is
>   performed; the value of nptr is stored in the object pointed to by endptr, provided
>   that endptr is not a null pointer.
>
> #### Returns
>
> ¶8 The strtol, strtoll, strtoul, and strtoull functions return the converted
>   value, if any. If no conversion could be performed, zero is returned. If the correct value
>   is outside the range of representable values, LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX, LLONG_MIN,
>   LLONG_MAX, ULONG_MAX, or ULLONG_MAX is returned (according to the return type
>   and sign of the value, if any), and the value of the macro ERANGE is stored in errno.

You would want to ensure that all the non-blank characters were converted, amongst other things.

Comment: @Mateo: you have to use `if (strcmp(argv[1], "-b") == 0)` to test the argument.

Answer (score 3):

In C you need to call [`strcmp(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) to compare strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if ((argc == 3) && (0 == strcmp(argv[1], "-b")) ) //here lies the problem
    {
        int n = 0;
        char *c_pt = argv[2];

        printf("argv[2]: %s\n", argv[2]);
        while (*c_pt)
        {
            if (*c_pt < '0' || *c_pt > '1')
            {
                break;
            }
            n = n * 2 + *c_pt - '0';
            c_pt++;
        }
        printf("%d\n", n);

    }
}
```

Allthough my version would rather use

```
char* end;
printf("%li\n", strtol(argv[2], &end, 2));
```